# Need to Impersonate user forAccessing Network resource, Asp.Net Account

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, impersonation, delegation

I need to access a network resource on which only a given Domain Account has access.
I am using the LogonUser call, but get a "User does not have required priviliege" exception, as the web application is running with the asp.net account and it does not have adequate permissions to make this call.

Is there a way to get around it?
Changing the identity or permissions of the ASP.Net account is not an option as this is a production machine with many projects running.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Using Asp.Net 2.0, Forms Authentication.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just calling LogonUser is not enough. You need to impersonate that user. You can impersonate for just the access to the network resource.

Sample code can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could add an

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName=""/>
```

tag to your web.config but that might not be ideal as you probably don't want to run the entire site as that user...

Can you map the network share as a local drive with the DomainName & Password... and then pull files to the website via the mapped drive ?

```
NET USE Z: \\SERVER\Share password /USER:DOMAIN\Username /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only had intimate experience with this under 1.1, so things might hav changed in the 2.0 days but...
We've got an app that gets deployed in intranet scenarios, and we strike the same thing. We run with identity impersonate turned on, forms mode authentication, anonymous access turned off. The easiest way to control this (that I've found) is to put the credentials of the user that has access in the web.config. They go on the node where you turn identity impersonate on. If it's super scret info I wouldn't do it this way though! We're only accessing shared graphics in a print environment, so most sites are happy to setup a limited account for us to put in the web.confit. 
LogonUser does indeed need elevated privelidges. Msdn has some good articles on how to impersonate a specific user in code. I'd fish out some links but this phone doesn't do copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the ACL protecting the network resource?  A trick I've used in the past is to  create an Active Directory group and then put the Computer Object into that group.  I then use that group in the Access Control List of the object (file, share, etc) that I need to access.

This has allowed me to run Windows Services as Local System and get access to the protected network resources.  And this trick also seems to work for the ASP.NET process which runs as Network Service.

Answer (score 0):

- With this WebPart y connect to a net resource with restricted access I put a file and y close the connection with the resource (as user with granted access), you dont need to make a new share connection, that was de only restricction, that my sistems departament make to me. May be, there are many imports that necesary, but I do to many tests and I havent got time to clean the code. I hope that help to you. (sorry for my poor english).

Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.File
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Environment
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

Public Class Impersonalizacion
    Private Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT As Integer = 0
    Private Const LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Integer = 2

```
<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function LogonUser(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint:="DuplicateToken", ExactSpelling:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function DuplicateToken(ByVal ExistingTokenHandle As IntPtr, ByVal ImpersonationLevel As Integer, ByRef DuplicateTokenHandle As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Function WinLogOn(ByVal strUsuario As String, ByVal strClave As String, ByVal strDominio As String) As WindowsImpersonationContext
    Dim tokenDuplicate As New IntPtr(0)
    Dim tokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)
    If LogonUser(strUsuario, strDominio, strClave, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, tokenHandle) Then
        If DuplicateToken(tokenHandle, 2, tokenDuplicate) <> 0 Then
            Return (New WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate)).Impersonate()
        End If
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

End Class
'Description for WebPart1.
"), XmlRoot(Namespace:="SPSCopiarFichero")> _
Public Class WebPart1
    Inherits Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart

```
Protected WithEvents File1 As HtmlInputFile

Dim vdestino As String = "\\centappd20nd01\uploads_avisos"
Dim vtemporal As String = "c:\pdf"

Protected WithEvents boton1 As Button
Protected WithEvents usuario As TextBox
Protected WithEvents contra As TextBox
Protected WithEvents dominio As TextBox
Protected WithEvents destino As TextBox
Protected WithEvents origen As TextBox
Protected WithEvents temporal As TextBox
Protected WithEvents log As TextBox
'Render this Web Part to the output parameter specified.
Protected Overrides Sub RenderWebPart(ByVal output As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    log.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><font>Ruta Origen</font><br>")
    File1.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><font>Ruta Temporal </font><br>")
    temporal.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><font>Ruta Destino </font><br>")
    destino.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><font>Usuario </font><br>")
    usuario.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><font>Contraseña </font><br>")
    contra.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><font>Dominio </font><br>")
    dominio.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("<br><br><center>")
    boton1.RenderControl(output)
    output.Write("</center>")
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()

    dominio = New TextBox
    With dominio
        .Text = "admon-cfnavarra"
        .Width = Unit.Pixel("255")
    End With
    Controls.Add(dominio)

    boton1 = New Button
    With boton1
        .Text = "Copiar Fichero"
    End With
    Controls.Add(boton1)

    File1 = New HtmlInputFile
    With File1

    End With
    Controls.Add(File1)

    usuario = New TextBox
    With usuario
        .Text = "SVCWSINCPre_SNS"
        .Width = Unit.Pixel("255")
    End With
    Controls.Add(usuario)

    contra = New TextBox
    With contra
        .Text = "SVCWSINCPre_SNS"
        .Width = Unit.Pixel("255")
    End With
    Controls.Add(contra)

    destino = New TextBox
    With destino
        .Text = vdestino
        .Width = Unit.Pixel("255")
    End With
    Controls.Add(destino)

    log = New TextBox
    With log
        .Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
        .BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        .ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    End With
    Controls.Add(log)

    temporal = New TextBox
    With temporal
        .Text = vtemporal
        .Width = Unit.Pixel("255")
    End With
    Controls.Add(temporal)
End Sub
Private Sub boton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles boton1.Click
    If File1.PostedFile.FileName <> "" Then
        Dim _objContext As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing
        log.Text = QuienSoy()
        CopyFile(File1.PostedFile.FileName, temporal.Text)
        _objContext = Impersonalizacion.WinLogOn(usuario.Text, contra.Text, dominio.Text)
        CopyFile(temporal.Text & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName), destino.Text)
        _objContext.Undo()
    Else
        log.Text = "Se debe introducir un fichero"
    End If
End Sub
Friend Shared Function QuienSoy() As String
    Return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
End Function
Public Function CopyFile(ByVal StartPath As String, ByVal EndPath As String)
    Try
        Dim fn As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(StartPath)
        System.IO.File.Copy(StartPath, EndPath & "\" & fn, False)
        log.Text = "Fichero Copiado Correctamente"
    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

End Class